# SCSS - nth-child(2) affects all descendants

Tags: css, sass

I have some code that looks like this:

```
  .my-class {

      :nth-child(2) {

         padding-right: 15px;
         padding-left: 0;
   ...
   ...
}}
```

This works fine.
The issues is that this also gets applied to all of `.my-class`'s descendants.

So for example, if under `.my-class` I also have a `<div className="test">...</div>`, the padding above will also be applied to the second child of that `div`.

Is this how CSS works? How can i just make sure this applies to the second child of `.my-class` and nothing else?

Comment: I think it should be `&:nth-child(2)`, the & attaches the pseudoclass directly to your class, otherwise all pseudo-classes underneath the class will be affected.

Comment: @user3154108 no. If they use the `&`, then the `my-class` will get the `:nth` selector, not the child elements.

Comment: @disinfor True, I thought that was the point XD

Comment: @user3154108, nah, they wanted the direct child element to be affected (_second child of .my-class and nothing else?_). CSS FUN!

Comment: @disinfor Yeah, I get that now, just my reading comprehension suffering at the end of my work day.

Comment: @user3154108 I feel you! And I just started my work day! hahahah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at how your SCSS actually gets compiled, you'll see it gets compiled to:

```
.my-class :nth-child(2) {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Because CSS cascades (hence cascading style sheet), your `:nth-child(2)` will affect every second child.

I changed the padding to the left side, so it can be seen.

```css
.my-class :nth-child(2) {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class">
  <div>
    first
    <div>
      first child
    </div>
    <div>
      second child
      <div>
        first - second child
      </div>
      <div>
        second - second child
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    second
  </div>

</div>
```

If you want to stop this, you need to get specific on the what the :nth-child(2) should be applied to.

Like this:

```css
.my-class > :nth-child(2) {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class">
  <div>
    first
    <div>
      first child
    </div>
    <div>
      second child
      <div>
        first - second child
      </div>
      <div>
        second - second child
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    second
  </div>

</div>
```

That essentially will only affect DIRECT children of `.my-class`.

Here's the SCSS:

```
.my-class {

       > :nth-child(2) {

         padding-right: 15px;
         padding-left: 0;

}}
```

Documentation for the direct child combinator `>`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator

Comment: Great, many thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: You're welcome!! I would recommend checking out all of the different selectors (if you haven't already), there are some fun ones. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

.my-class {

```
   > :nth-child(2) {

     padding-right: 15px;
     padding-left: 0;
```

}}

the operator ">" means that you want just for himself